# How to use "valueforkey"?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to do the following - I have an Array in which some strings are stored. These strings shall be used to call an NSArray. An example will clarify what I'm trying to do:

This is the working code that I'm trying to achieve ("briefing0" is of type NSArray):

```
NSString *path = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[briefing0 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

This is the "same" code that I'm trying to use:

```
int i = 0;
NSString *path = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[(NSArray *)[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"briefing%d", i] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!
Tom

Comment: You mean any idea what your question is?  No.

Comment: I re-phrased my question. Rob's answer was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `briefing0` is actually a property, then yes, this is possible (and not uncommon) in ObjC via [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).

```
int i = 0;
NSString *prop = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"briefing%d", i];
NSArray *array = [self valueForKey:prop];
NSString *value = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
... etc. ...
```

`-valueForKey:` is the piece you're looking for. Note that this will throw an exception if you construct a key that does not exist, and so must be used with extreme care.